# Does the Flash Gordon Film continue in any media after the "The End ?"

Tags: flash-gordon, sequel

At the end of the Flash Gordon Flim we see the ring that Ming the Merciless was wearing get picked up by an unknown hand and the EPIC words "The End ?"

First is this story continued in any media?
Second do we know who picked it up ?

Comment: The hand appears to be Ming's.  And does the homage in *Ted* count as "continuing" the story?

Comment: Apparently there's a sequel in the offing; http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/sam-jones-says-new-flash-gordon-sequel/ - Stuck in development hell though.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miU6ruUPZHI

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcTPhAp3Ax8

Comment: What's the second thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, no subsequent *Flash Gordon* works are part of the 1980 film continuity.

After the film's release, [various](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon) *Flash Gordon*-themed cartoons, comics, games and other works were created. However, none of them were based off or related to the 1980 movie.

The [2007 live-action series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(2007_TV_series)) did apparently have a few elements similar to those of the film, but not the ongoing plot. The Queen song was also used in its advertising.

Comment: ...so yeah. You can mentally replace that question mark with a period.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's still a question, except the answer is a firm "Yes."